# postgresql could not create user

Tags: postgresql

I installed Postgresql with following commands:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ precise-pgdg main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list"
wget --quiet -O - http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install postgresql-common
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.3 libpq-dev
```

As postgresql installation doesn't set up a user I manually tried to create it. But, I get this strange error.

```
➜  ~  sudo -u postgres createuser cooldudeabhi -s
createuser: could not connect to database postgres: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Comment: What do you get from `sudo service postgresql status`?

Comment: @Kevin  postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Comment: Try running `sudo systemctl enable postgresql.service` (and possibly `sudo systemctl start postgresql.service` as well).